# SSH is not working .. Password promt is not coming

Tags: ssh, password

I am not able to SSH into my ubuntu server since yesterday.

I am not using any keyless or public key method..
Its simple SSH with username and password everytime..

However I can do a VNC session running on my ubuntu server.. But I am afraid that if the vnc session goes out, I wont be having any way to login to the server..

My ssh-vvv output is as below..

```
sumanth@sumanth:~$ ssh -vvv user@serverIP
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 172.16.2.156 [172.16.2.156] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/sumanth/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/sumanth/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/sumanth/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/sumanth/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/sumanth/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/sumanth/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/sumanth/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/sumanth/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1 pat OpenSSH_5* compat 0x0c000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "172.16.2.156" from file "/home/sumanth/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type ECDSA in file /home/sumanth/.ssh/known_hosts:5
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: mac_setup: setup hmac-md5
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug2: mac_setup: setup hmac-md5
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA ea:4e:15:52:15:dd:6b:09:d4:36:cb:14:2d:c3:1b:7a
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "172.16.2.156" from file "/home/sumanth/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type ECDSA in file /home/sumanth/.ssh/known_hosts:5
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug1: Host '172.16.2.156' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/sumanth/.ssh/known_hosts:5
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /home/sumanth/.ssh/id_rsa ((nil)),
debug2: key: /home/sumanth/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil)),
debug2: key: /home/sumanth/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil)),
debug2: key: /home/sumanth/.ssh/id_ed25519 ((nil)),
```

Comment: Does your ssh actually give an error, or does it just exit? Check /etc/ssh_config, see if it's changed.

Comment: Which Ubuntu version is the server running? Is `UseDNS` defined in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`? Any hints in `/var/log/auth.log`?

Comment: @Sobrique: Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Comment: @Sobrique:No SSH error. it gets stuck before password prompt.. It doesnt even exit.
I saw /etc/ssh/etc_config file. No changes are there..

Comment: @kasperd:  Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
No UseDNS is not defined in /etc/ssh/sshd_config
No hints in /var/log/auth.log

Comment: @SumanthLingappa Is it logging anything at all, when you try to log in? If nothing is logged at all, you may have run out of disk space.

Comment: So it's stalling mid way through - usually when it connects to a server it'll either time out or get a connection refused. If it's doing neither, then it suggests something else is going on. I would suggest that you need `strace` next (or platform specific equivalent).  Try: `strace -fTt ssh <user>@<host>` and look at which system call is blocking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing that can slow down ssh login is when the server tries to perform DNS lookups on the address of the client. Usually this will not break login completely, but either way it is worth turning off.

Add this to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

```
UseDNS no
```

And then type `service ssh reload` in the shell.

Comment: It worked @kasperd.. wow, thanks alot !!! Thanks alot for the help